# Can I setup a Ubuntu desktop as a switch?

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I want to setup a VBox Ubuntu to receive and send packets using a single interface from/to the rest of connected PCs.

Comment: How do you connect more than one PC with a single interface?

Comment: Here, we are assuming a "virtual" interface. The "router" Ubuntu can receive the packets from other instances from a single interface. I just want to forward the incoming packets to the rest. Which is the best approach?

Comment: I guess you need to turn on IP forwarding in the kernel. Here's how to do it: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-turn-on-off-ip-forwarding-in-linux

Comment: Yes, I've done that an added `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -s 192.168.1.1 --dport 8947 -j ACCEPT` however, I get icmp destination unreachable port unreachable on wireshark. Note that this instances already are transmitting udp through port 8947. Should I change the port of this FORWARD?

Comment: Can I modify the above command to receive from 8947 and send to another port?